# I can't see "Logback Beagle" in eclipse Window >> show view>> other

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation, logback

I went to the tutorial on this http://logback.qos.ch/beagle/ link to install Logback Beagle in eclipse. It installed successfully as I can't see it in Eclipse's installed programs. But I cant open it in Window >> Show view >> other
I have also tried completely removing all of this, repeating steps same steps given in tutorial as fresh, but none worked.
Where could I be wrong?

My system has **WIN8, JAVA8, Eclipse Standard/SDK version Kepler Release**

Comment: Have you installed Nebula Grid before? (it is needed to run Beagle). Also, maybe this plugin doesn't work anymore with Kepler, since it was not updated for more than 2 years... (have you tried with Indigo/Juno?). If you're looking for a log viewer, you can try [LogMX](http://www.logmx.com), it handles Logback log files, and many other formats.